# RabbitMQ Publish to Exchange Confirmation

Tags: callback, rabbitmq, exchange-server, publish, producer

I would like to return a retrieve a confirmation that the message was successfully published to the exchange before closing the AMQP connection. At the moment, I am using a timeout function to allow for the message to be published before closing the connection. This is not the right way. Can someone please help to retrieve a confirmation so I can close the connection based on a successful publish?

The code I am using is below:

```
function toExchange(msg)
{
    amqp.connect('amqp://localhost:5672', function(err, conn) //local connection
    {
        conn.createChannel(function(err, ch)
        {
            var exchange = 'MessageExchange';
            ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'fanout', {durable: true});
            ch.publish(exchange, '', new Buffer(msg));
            console.log("Sent to Exchange: %s", msg);
        });
        setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); }, 5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Which language/library are you using?

Comment: NodeJS and using the amqplib library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RabbitMQ extension called "Publisher confirms". Here is more information: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms.

You are not notified when the message is published to the exchange, but **when it is published and routed to all queues**: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#when-publishes-are-confirmed

In your case using amqplib in nodeJS you can use this snippet of code: https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#confirmchannel

It uses the callback `#waitForConfirms(function(err) {...})` that triggers when all published messages have been confirmed.

Comment: I've seen that but in terms of code, how do I implement it? That is what is confusing me.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link that shows the API reference. I hope that helps you.